# docker Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I have running docker and when want to send request from docker to my rails server 
i have got

```
curl localhost:3000
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:3000; Connection refused
```

but my rails server has been started.

```
    docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        2016-10-26T23:26:11.105168198+00:00
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

i have started docker with `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`

upd My rails server outside docker container

Comment: Are you using docker for mac/windows or the older docker toolbox?

Comment: @R0MANARMY for mac

Comment: if your rails server is running in your container, you have to expose the port at the moment of starting 3000:3000, or if you use docker-compose, you can declare it on the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: @unmultimedio My rails server outside docker container

Answer (score 0):

As I see you use `docker-machine` so you have to use the `docker-machine IP` and not localhost. To get docker-machine IP, use `docker-machine ip` command.